# Create key if it doesn't exist in nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to figure out how to write this ruby code more eloquently. Does someone have a better solution?

```
a[:new] = {} if a[:new].nil?
a[:new].merge!( { new_key => new_value } )
```

is there a way to write this in a more elegant way? I come across this a lot when dealing with nested hashes that need to check whether an key exist and if not, create it.

Comment: try with it `a[:new]||= {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as below taking the help of [`Hash#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_h) and [`NilClass#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_h)

```
a[:new] = a[:new].to_h.merge( { new_key => new_value } )
```

Example :

```
hsh1[:a] # => nil
hsh1[:a] = hsh1[:a].to_h.merge({1=>2})
hsh1[:a] # => {1=>2}

hsh2 = {:a => {'k' => 2}}
hsh2[:a] # => {"k"=>2}
hsh2[:a] = hsh2[:a].to_h.merge({1=>2})
hsh2 # => {:a=>{"k"=>2, 1=>2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this at the beginning:

```
a = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = {}}
```

then, without caring whether `a` has a key `:new` or not, do

```
a[:new].merge!(new_key => new_value)
```

or

```
a[:new][new_key] = new_value
```